# problem with a list checking mini algorithm in python

Tags: python, arrays

i want to make a mini programme to get all the couples(x,y) of a list that satisfy 'x+y = sum'

```
ar= [1,2,3,4,5,3,6,7,9,8,10,13,18]

sum = 9


for i in ar:

    noclubs = [x for x in ar if x != ar[i]]
    for z in noclubs:
        if ar[i] + noclubs[z] == sum:
            print(ar[i],noclubs[z])
```

it shows me this error" if ar[i] + noclubs[z] == sum:
IndexError: list index out of range"

here is the code
plz help me

Comment: The `for .. in ..` syntax doesn't give you the index, it gives you the value directly

Comment: Check what the value of `i` is and if that is what you think it is.

Comment: `i` and `z` are already the ***elements*** of the lists, not the ***index***

Answer (score 0):

You can use iteration variables instead

```
ar= [1,2,3,4,5,3,6,7,9,8,10,13,18]

sum = 9


for i in ar:

    noclubs = [x for x in ar if x != i]
    for z in noclubs:
        if i + z == sum:
            print(i,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

More code but potentially more efficient. This is because if any element in the list is greater than or equal to the target value then there's no point in including it or any higher in the calculations. So:

```
from itertools import combinations

ar = [1,1,2,3,4,5,3,6,7,9,8,10,13,18]

total = 9

def get_pairs(a, s):
    result = set()
    for combo in combinations([e for e in a if e < s], 2):
        if sum(combo) == s:
            result.add(combo)
    return result

print(get_pairs(ar, total))
```

**Output:**

```
{(4, 5), (1, 8), (2, 7), (3, 6)}
```